# Terminating a DialogFragment using a onclicklistener

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, dialogfragment

I'm trying to create a `DialogFragment` class that allows you to enter in four fields, and click a "done" button. Upon clicking the button, the `DialogFragment` should change certain text values and then terminate back to the main screen.

So far I have it doing everything I want it to do, except the terminating. The Dialog changes the selected `TextView` to "hello" and just lingers.

Can anyone show me how to get it to go away? Thanks!

```
public class TeamFragment extends DialogFragment {
    TextView team1, team2, score1, score2;

    public TeamFragment(View t1, View t2, View s1, View s2) {
        team1=(TextView) t1;
        team2=(TextView) t2;
        score1=(TextView) s1;
        score2=(TextView) s2;
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.team_score_layout, container);
        //mEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_your_name);
        getDialog().setTitle("Enter Team Name");
        Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.teamButton);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
            team1.setText("hello");

          }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `public Dialog onCreateDialog()` instead of the `View onCreateView`?

Comment: Are you trying to dismiss the dialog or are you trying to pop the back stack to a later screen?

Comment: @TronicZomB The main reason I did the oncreateview was that I wanted to be able to access the xml file team_score_layout. Would creating a dialog allow me to use this xml file while being able to exit the dialog?

Also, I'm trying to create a dialog window on top of a main screen, and once i am done with the dialog, be able to essentially pop the window and go back to the main screen.

Comment: Yea you can still set the view via an xml with the `onCreateDialog`. Use `LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();` and then on your AlertDialog Builder you can use `builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.name_dialog, null));` and at the end `return builder.create();` and when you call this fragment just create a new instance of it like any other fragment and then just do myDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "TAG");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dismiss the [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) using the following method

```
dismiss()
```